# Нужна ли в данном предложении запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

Если пациент, серьезно нарушивший правило(-а), просит о повторном зачислении и медицинский персонал одобряет запрос, пациент должен оплатить стоимость зачисления в полном объеме (1950 евро).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А. **(1)Если пациент просит и (2)[если] персонал одобряет, (3)пациент должен оплатить.**

Я вижу так: предложения (1) и (2) — придаточные, выражающие условия, которые являются причиной или обоснованием того, о чём говорится в главном предложении (3).
Оно общее для двух однородных придаточных предложений, поэтому запятая перед **и** не ставится.
[Запятая перед союзом «И»](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

Б. Если пациент нарушил только одно правило, пишем окончание **-о**;
если же были нарушены два правила или более, то используется множественное число — окончание **-а.**
Обычно используется множественное число, потому что в каждом медицинском учреждении такой свод правил имеется (***Правила*** пользования... или ***Правила*** нахождения...).

**Если пациент, серьезно нарушивший правила, просит о повторном зачислении и медицинский персонал одобряет запрос, пациент должен оплатить стоимость зачисления в полном объеме (1950 евро).**

Answer (score 0):

К сказанному в ответе Риммы Михайловой добавлю, что в тексте есть "шероховатости":

- Если пациент просит о повторном зачислении, значит он был отчислен, но в тексте говорится о нарушении правил, а не об отчислении. Это можно считать логической ошибкой.
- "Если один делает, то другой должен..." — такая конструкция говорит о том, что действия первого **вынуждают** второго что-то предпринять. А в нашем случае такой обусловленности нет, у нас пациент **должен** платить не потому, что его просьбу утвердили, а для того, чтобы его приняли. Так что использованная конструкция не подходит.
- "Серьезно нарушивший" звучит просторечно. Если пациент был отчислен за нарушение правил, то и так ясно, что нарушение было "серьезным".
- Просьба и запрос — не одно и то же.

Вариант исправления:

**Для повторного зачисления пациенту, отчисленному за нарушение правил, необходимо получить согласие медицинского персонала и оплатить стоимость зачисления в полном объеме (1950 евро).**